# qooxdoo and debian lenny

Tags: python, debian, qooxdoo, lenny

Hy,

Trying to use qooxdoo with debian lenny.
qooxdoo sdk 1.2

create-application.py ok but I've got a problem with generate.py :

```
/demo/qooxdoo/hello1$ ./generate.py source-all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/demo/qooxdoo-1.2-sdk/tool/bin/generator.py", line 26, in <module>
    from generator.Generator import Generator
  File "/demo/qooxdoo-1.2-sdk/tool/bin/Generator.py", line 31, in <module>
    #import warnings
  File "/demo/qooxdoo-1.2-sdk/tool/bin/Generator.py", line 31, in <module>
    #import warnings
ImportError: No module named code.Class
```

I do think I'm missing some debian packages

Do please help me. Ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stack trace is a tad weird. For a basic thing, the referenced code line (Generator.py:31) imports from "generator.code.Class", and the ImportError indicates that it doesn't find the "code" subpackage under "generator". But the "#import warnings" line is actually generator.py line 31, as if it would be mixing generator.py and Generator.py.

This is furthered by the fact that the stack trace references /demo/qooxdoo-1.2-sdk/tool/bin/Generator.py, which should really be /demo/qooxdoo-1.2-sdk/tool/pylib/generator/Generator.py

I don't have a lenny handy to check if the package itself is alright, but I get the feeling there is some basic flaw with how the qooxdoo SDK is installed on your machine.

I recommend that you simply download the qooxdoo-1.2-sdk from [sourceforge](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/qooxdoo/qooxdoo-1.2-sdk.zip) and unpack it to a suitable directory. Then re-run the create-application.py from this package to create a new skeleton, or edit the config.json of your existing skeleton so that the QOOXDOO_PATH macro points to the new SDK. Then you should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem too when I had unpacked the zip file in a virtual box shared directory (host XP, guest Ubuntu), the share caused this issue when I ran `./generate.py` source within the shared directory.

When I unpacked the zip to a normal Linux directory, I had no problems.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with zamnut6. I've had the same problem when I extracted the qooxdoo SDK package on a a virtualbox shared HFS filesystem. The problem is something to do with file name casing incompatibility between two file systems.

Extracting the SDK on a normal Linux directory (if your development environment is Linux) should solve this issue.